# How to pass the value for invocationCount from the testNG test plan

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I know we can use the invocationCount to repeat the test method for the given number like below:

```
@Test(invocationCount = 10)
public void example() {    
       System.out.println("Bla Bla");
}
```

I want to set the "invocationCount" (repeat count) at the runtime from testNG test plan. But since annotations accepts only constants I couldn't pass a dynamic variable as value for invocationCount. Is there a way to acheive this?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement an `IAnnotationTransformer` to change the value of `innvocationCount` at runtime. Refer to this in official documents - http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers. There is an exact implementation in it for what you are attempting.